# Fast publishing in wordpress

Tags: posts, wp-admin, performance

Wodpress editor is too slow. How to create other faster interface or how to fast publish posts. I just need fileds for author, category and subtitle. Is there any way instead of default wordpress editor ?

Comment: Subtitle? Is that some kind of custom field in your site? You can hide almost every part of the posting screen via "Screen Options" - have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

I get what you want, it will require some coding skills though.

What I did was create myself a plugin that registers a new menu page, and then I use 
    wp_insert_post()
function to create a post with given parameters. You can check out my plugin here: 
http://www.mediafire.com/?499tk848njaz7hq

It's for fast image posting, but I believe you can adjust it to your need.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Press This</kbd> (`/wp-admin/tools.php`) does *almost* what you ask for.

[image: press this tool]

Just drag the button to your bookmarks bar. Clicking it will open the following popup:

[image: press this popup]

The matter is that it grabs the current browser window title and selected content. But this can be easily changed. It does not have the `Author` option though, nor `Custom Fields`.